# Creating a Custom Seekbar

Tags: android, custom-controls, seekbar

I was creating an app like a book reading app. but i want my app have this 
![option][1].

I think all of you have experience of using it, this option allow the reader to scroll to skip the page that they dont wanna read, so can u guys share some way to make it exist?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1zFx.png  :(

Comment: I'm asking someone to show me some way. Plz see it carefully.

Comment: How will you show tour content? Plaintext ?

Comment: The data from the sql lite.

Comment: Custom seekbar: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seek_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_cyan"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_red"/>

</layer-list>
```

[this](http://javandroidevelop.blogspot.in/2012/09/cool-seekbar-custom-made-by-me.html) link help your more.

or you can try [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/androids-seekbar-your-way/943/)